# Would this self-Q&A be on-topic on Ask Different?

Tags: discussion

Normally, any game compiled with a modern version of Unity (I think maybe Unity 2018 or newer?) will crash on startup on OS X 10.9, with the message:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: _getattrlistbulk
```

But, I got them to work by injecting some code to stub that missing symbol. The need to work around two-level namespacing made this *much* more annoying than it should have been.

I really need to document this process somewhere, and I've been thinking of posting a self-Q&A on this site. However, because the fix is basically to write and compile a bit of C code, I'm concerned the answer would be considered off-topic on Ask Different. On the other hand, this isn't the type of development question that would make sense on e.g. StackOverflow.

Any thoughts? I just don't want to spend a couple of hours writing something that will be closed. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go ahead and post it. It‘s a bit borderline, but using C code to solve an enduser problem isn‘t so much different from installing a tool via Homebrew.

Also, even if it gets closed (which I doubt) the post will remain and should even be able to get votes.

Comment: Agreed. Short question, answer that solves a practical question and teaches how things work is awesome. The point of off topic is unanswered questions due to missing skill sets or the noise created waiting for a proper answer. I can’t see either issue triggering with a self answered post.

Comment: Thanks! Question is here btw. :) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414688/how-do-i-run-newer-unity-games-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks/414689

Comment: Just be sure to tell us how you really feel about graphical redesigns and skeuomorphic effects @Wowfunhappy :-)